# Chromedriver installed but not working Linux

Tags: linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-12.04, undetected-chromedriver

> Hello folks, I have just installed Chromedriver on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 22 04 destro), and moved the directory after unzipping it to /usr/local/bin/ and when I execute chromedriver --version in my terminal it shows it's installed and it tells it's version [Chromedirver installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7oRU.png), However when I go execute a python code using selenium the and get request to a website it doesn't open up on my google chrome and laterally nothing happens. please help!
> [My terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmxL0.png) and here's the [Python code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k40PM.png)

I tried to run "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrad -y" command to make sure I'm up to date and I rebooted a couple times.